# Positioning iframe

Tags: html, iframe, position

So I have this iframe code that centers iframe content. It is working, but it stays on the top of the page, how could  get it more down?

```
 <h3 style="text-align:center;" >
<iframe src="http://88.90.5.113:12/customexportfile.htm" width="200" 
height="100" frameBorder="0"  ></iframe>
</h3>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried something like this: `margin-top: 20px;`?